# What is the source for the definition of infinite and infinitesimal for linearly ordered groups?

Tags: reference-request, infinitesimals

On Wikipedia, I found a definition of infinite and infinitesimal for linearly ordered groups that states the following:

> $x$ is *infinitesimal with respect to $y$* (or equivalently, *$y$ is infinite with respect to $x$*) if, for every natural number $n$, the
>   multiple $nx$ is less than $y$.

The link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Definition_for_linearly_ordered_groups

Unfortunately, there is no source given. Does anyone know a good source for this definition?

Comment: It is the "obvious" definition, but I don't know why _authoritative_ source for it.

Comment: @Arthur: Do you know any source where it is used in this way?

Comment: The authoritative source is Euclid. Broadly, he said that a quantity can be measured by another if a multiple of the latter exceeds the former.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I guess Euclid did not use therms "infinitesimal" and "infinite". Do you happen to know any source from the mathematical literature where the definition is given as above?

Comment: @Daniel Of course he didn't use “infinite” nor “infinitesimal”. However, already in ancient times there were discussions about the angle formed by a circle and a tangent to it, no multiple of which can exceed a linear angle, possibly the first discovered example of an infinitesimal quantity.

Comment: @egreg: I guess this doesn't answer my question but it is interesting.

Comment: I imagine this comes up in a number of sources. For example, definition II.4.6 in Siegel's "Combinatorial Game Theory" gives this definition (and notation $x\ll y$) in the particular context of combinatorial games. I don't personally know of a source on, say, totally ordered groups that could serve as a general authoritative source.